# Filtering elements with certain classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'll try to make this as clear as possible so I don't confuse anyone. What I'm attempting to do is, I have a collection of divs, that all start with the `display: none`. Each `div` has a different set of classes, except they will all share the `class="card"` and some of the divs will share the same classes. So for example:

```
<div class="card simple rough arcuate">

</div>

<div class="card simple smooth needle">

</div>
```

So what I want to do is, using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), make cards appear when a checkbox with one of their corresponding classes is checked and disappear if a checkbox that doesn't correspond with one of their classes is checked. So if the checkbox with the checkbox with `"simple"` is checked they both appear, if a checkbox with `"rough"` is clicked, then the second one disappears. This is what I've tried so far.

```
$('#simple').change(function() {
   if ($('.card').hasClass('simple') && $('#simple').prop("checked")) {
    $('.card').show() 
  } else {
    $('.card').hide()
  }
});

$('#arcuate').change(function() {
  if ($('.card').hasClass('arcuate') && $('#arcuate').prop("checked")) {
    $('.card').show()
  } else {
   $('.card').hide()
  }
});
```

Just for posterity's sake here are a few of the checkboxes:

```
<label><input id="simple" type="checkbox"/>Simple</label>
<label id="arcuate"><input type="checkbox"/>Arcuate</label>
<label id="rough"><input type="checkbox"/>Rough</label>
<label id="smooth"><input type="checkbox"/>Smooth</label>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and we can help you.

Comment: Show what you have tried and provide a [mcve]. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing or tutorial service

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways You could achieve this. You can use jQuery's [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

```
$('.card').hide().filter('.'+your_class).show();
```

if they are [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('.card').filter('.'+your_class).show().siblings().hide();
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: `hasClass()` returns a boolean. It is not a selector filter

Answer (score 0):

Class selectors are a `.myclass` dot and id a `#myid`.  Use the class for your example.  Simplify a bit.

In this instance I added a data attribute and query that for the class to show.
Now you simply add more inputs and/or divs and no code changes to show those that are checked.  Note that I hooked to a div with an id and simply select those in that that, setting the values visible that are checked.

No need to maintain a bunch of id's here.

```js
$('.card').toggle(false);// initial hide
$('#toggles').on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(event) {
    var checks = $(event.delegateTarget).find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    checks
    .filter(':checked')
    .each(function(){
        var targets = $(this).data("target");
        $('.card.'+targets).show();
    });
    checks
    .filter(":not(:checked)")
    .each(function(){
         var targets = $(this).data("target");
         $('.card.'+targets).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggles">
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-target="simple" />Simple</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-target="arcuate"/>Arcuate</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-target="rough"  />Rough</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-target="smooth" />Smooth</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-target="needle" />Needle</label>
</div>
<div class="card simple rough arcuate">simple rough arcuate</div>
<div class="card simple smooth needle">simple smooth needle</div>
<div class="card simple needle">simple needle</div>
<div class="card simple rough">simple rough</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate showing me how to cut down on the IDs. So your solution looks very similar to what I want, but when I run the code. If I check "simple", then check rough, it doesn't filter out the other two divs. If that makes sense.

Comment: This is "inclusive" note that checking "simple" will show those with simple = and they all have that.  If you wish to have it be "totally inclusive" i.e. show only those with BOTH classes you could alter the logic to do so - i.e. hide those that are "unchecked".  That would differ from your original posting.

Comment: I altered this so that it must include "ALL" the classes to display - so since they all include "simple" then than one, then if you choose "rough" only the simple && rough one shows.  Perhaps that is what you desire - note that if you wish the OLD logic, review the "edit" history.  This does have an order dependency (show first, then hide those not checked).